# iPhone app is controlling itself without IBAction

Tags: iphone, ibaction, touchesbegan

I have a simple application. It is you touch start button, then the display will change, then you shake your iPhone, it shows you some texts. The problem I am having now is first time the app was developed for iOS 3.0. Since then the codes weren't touched. Last week I upgraded my Xcode into version 4.2. Then my app is controlling itself no touches required. It will control itself. When I modified the `touchesbegan` function, it doesn't change. Neither the accelerometer does. So what could be the problem?